# Do we need downloaded components to run an app in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am installing android for the first time on my computer, but "Downloading Components" taking lots of time.
I want to test and run some very small apps. Can i do without those components.
Do i really need that at start.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer: **Yes** you need them!

(I am assuming that you have the sourcecode of an app and you want to build it with android studio. If thats not the case check the answer of Beppi's.)

---

You can read about this components in the following links. This will give you a understanding why you need to download them separately regarding to their version you use:

- SDK Build Tools: [Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html)
- SdkVersions: [Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)
- Gradle: [Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make and run a source code, as MarkB said, the answer is ten times yes.
But your question is unclear: if you need to install an already compiled app, in form of apk, then you don't need the entire Android Studio, you can just get an emulator. Avoid the official Android emulators, that are heavy and painfully slow, and get one of the many free emulators that are available with a [quick search on google](https://www.google.it/webhp#safe=on&q=android+free+emulator).